# Putty solarized the manual way

Tags: putty, bashrc, solarized

I would like to use the [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color scheme in [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/). The tricky part is **I don't have administrator privileges** in this machine. So I will have to manually change the default colors through Change Settings > Window > Colors.

I'm looking for a correspondence table with solarized RGB colors and PuTTY color names:

- Default Foreground
- Default Bold Foreground
- Default Background
- Default Bold Background
- Cursor Text
- Cursor Colour
- ANSI Black
- ANSI Black Bold
- ANSI Red
- ANSI Red Bold
- ANSI Green
- ANSI Green Bold
- ANSI Yellow
- ANSI Yellow Bold
- ANSI Blue
- ANSI Blue Bold
- ANSI Magenta
- ANSI Magenta Bold
- ANSI Cyan
- ANSI Cyan Bold
- ANSI White
- ANSI White Bold

I also accept any color scheme that is remotely better than PuTTY's default...

**EDIT:**

A saner way of doing this is to tick all the boxes in `Settings -> Windows -> Colour` and then, *in the remote machine*, add the line

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

or

```
export TERM=xterm
```

to `~/.bashrc` and create the file `~\.Xresources` with the [Solarized color scheme](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/xresources/solarized).

Comment: You *can* write to the current user hive (HKCU) without administrative permissions. You just can't use the built-in `regedit` to do it, but the built-in `reg` (command-line) would work, as would many third-party editors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you go:

- Default Foreground: 131, 148, 150
- Default Bold Foreground: 147, 161, 161
- Default Background: 0, 43, 54
- Default Bold Background: 7, 54, 66
- Cursor Text: 0, 43, 54
- Cursor Colour: 131, 148, 150
- ANSI Black: 7, 54, 66
- ANSI Black Bold: 0, 43, 54
- ANSI Red: 220, 50, 47
- ANSI Red Bold: 203, 75, 22
- ANSI Green: 133, 153, 0
- ANSI Green Bold: 88, 110, 117
- ANSI Yellow: 181, 137, 0
- ANSI Yellow Bold: 101, 123, 131
- ANSI Blue: 38, 139, 210
- ANSI Blue Bold: 131, 148, 150
- ANSI Magenta: 211, 54, 130
- ANSI Magenta Bold: 108, 113, 196
- ANSI Cyan: 42, 161, 152
- ANSI Cyan Bold: 147, 161, 161
- ANSI White: 238, 232, 213
- ANSI White Bold: 253, 246, 227

(N.B.: You can download [a portable version of PuTTY](http://jakub.kotrla.net/putty/) that doesn't require admin privileges and stores its configuration in a local file instead of the registry. You can then edit those files with a text editor.)

Comment: Make sure you save the colors under Default Settings or any new sessions you save won't realize the colors

Comment: With these settings the all BOLD colors are almost gray. So, I currently set all bold colors same as non-bold colors. Do we have any official fix from solarized for this?

Answer (score 5):

Portable Putty is the way to go... not just for the fact you don't need Admin, but just the convenience of being able to copy sessions and settings easily from one PC to another (I save mine on my NAS)

Anyway, I've typed in the colours into Portable Putty, and extracted the relevant part of the conf file for your pleasure. 
As Ravindranath Akila said in the comments above, make you you also save to the default profile.

```
Colour21\253,246,227\
Colour20\238,232,213\
Colour19\147,161,161\
Colour18\42,161,152\
Colour17\108,113,196\
Colour16\211,54,130\
Colour15\131,148,150\
Colour14\38,139,210\
Colour13\101,123,131\
Colour12\181,137,0\
Colour11\88,110,117\
Colour10\133,153,0\
Colour9\203,75,22\
Colour8\220,50,47\
Colour7\0,43,54\
Colour6\7,54,66\
Colour5\131,148,150\
Colour4\0,43,54\
Colour3\7,54,66\
Colour2\0,43,54\
Colour1\147,161,161\
Colour0\131,148,150\
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Downloaded portable putty, but I do not see any conf files... :/

Answer (score 1):

Without administrative privileges, you can import a .reg file and apply it to your HKCU (which [Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) alluded to above).

1. In Windows, open a command prompt (cmd).
2. Enter `reg import <path\to\.reg\file>`

With this [solarized_dark.reg](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/putty-colors-solarized/solarized_dark.reg) file, it created a session named "Solarized Dark," which I then applied to the default.

Comment: Note that the Windows administrator may still restrict the use of reg, so this isn't guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give this a look. :)

https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/putty-colors-solarized

Comment: Maybe not. __I do not have administrator privileges__, so I neither can install `Putty Tray` or change the `Windows Registry`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this needs clarification. There may have been one release of Windows Vista or 7 where regedit required admin rights, however this has not been the case for most of history. When opening regedit, you will be prompted to elevate permissions, which requires your own user credentials (not an admin). Then regedit will open and you will have access to your own HKCU as well as other hives/keys that have public permissions.